# WordPress 'comment counts' got messed up, because of a plugin - DISQUS

Tags: comments, database

I use wordpress and disqus plugin,
when user add comment, after few minute, disqus agent will update wordpress database (wp_posts,wp_comments …etc),but when administrator delete comment, disqus will not update wp_posts's comment_count and wp_comments,

I can't get accuracy comment_count and comment counts got messed up, how could I get accuracy comment_count of every post ?

Thanks.

Sonic

Answer (score 1):

Try the Web Ninja Comment Count Fixer plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/web-ninja-comment-count-fixer/